# Setting up SFML in Codeblocks cant find "-lsfml-graphics"

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I tried installing sfml on windows in codeblocks using c++ by following the tutorial in their website and also by following tutorials on the web but even after all that it doesnt work and it gives out this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in dasg (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-graphics-s|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-window-s|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-system-s|
ld.exe||cannot find -lfreetype|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

In my compiler settings i have in the #define tab writen "SFML_STATIC"

In the linker setting i have the following link libraries

- sfml-graphics-s
- sfml-window-s
- sfml-system-s
- opengl32
- freetype
- gdi32
- winmm

In the search directories in the compiler sub tab i have the path to my sfml/include folder and in the linker subfolder I have the path to my sfml/lib

Did i do something wrong or did i forget something?

Comment: You are building in Debug mode. Are you sure you linked the libraries in the Debug settings, not Release? Did you use SFML libraries with `-d` suffix there?

Comment: In my linked libraries in the debug settings i have "sfml-graphics-d / sfml-window-d / sfml-system-d / opengl32"

Comment: In static debug you need both suffixes `-s` and `-d`, like this: `sfml-graphics-s-d`. Does that help?

Comment: Im sorry can you tell me where i can access the static debug?

Comment: You said that you have the `SFML-STATIC` macro defined in compiler settings, so you are linking SFML statically. That's why you need to link the SFML library files with the `-s` suffix. For Debug compilation mode you need to link the files that also have the `-d` suffix. You should have the `-s-d` files in your `SFML/lib` folder.

Comment: I changed it to sfml-graphics-s-d and the other ones also but it now the error message also involves those ones and the ones that i put in the debug settings

Comment: Only SFML libraries are suffixed. The other are the same.

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/a/jIxmFBL

Comment: Yes, exactly. What are your errors now?

Comment: its still the same unfortunatly https://imgur.com/a/c49joBp

Comment: Can't be exactly the same, you changed the linked files. Do you mean that it cannot find the `-s-d` files this time? Did you make sure they are in the folder you've given to Linker Search Directories?

Comment: This is the linker search directory https://imgur.com/a/tRAOGyz and this is the folder and its contents https://imgur.com/a/FWO5MiW

Comment: Well, if these are your settings for the Debug mode, then it should work now. I don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: ill try to uninstall codeblocks and install it again and configure it to see if it solves anything

Comment: Worth to try. Does it work in Release? If that won't work either, try to compile with GCC without Codeblocks.

Comment: It still doesnt work unfortunatly :C not even in release, i tried to compile with gcc and it gives out an error saying that SFML/Graphics.hpp: no such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221517/discussion-between-radoslav-voydanovich-and-andre-sousa).

Answer (score 1):

First check do you have a static or dynamic version of your library.
In your library  path check the files in /lib folder. if they have extension .so for example libsfml-graphics.so .

Go with this tutorial -> https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php